# Ramda: How to remove keys in objects with empty values?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, javascript-objects, ramda.js

I have this object:

```js
let obj = {
  matrimonyUrl: 'christian-grooms',
  search_criteria:
    'a:2:{s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:9:"community";s:9:"Christian";}',
  mothertongue: null,
  religion: 'Christian',
  caste: '',
  country: null
};
```

I need to remove all key/value pairs in this object where the value is blank i.e. `''`

So the `caste: ''` property should be removed in the above case.

I have tried:

```
R.omit(R.mapObjIndexed((val, key, obj) => val === ''))(obj);
```

But this doesn't do anything. `reject` doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you also interested in a solution which removes empty keys in nested objects?

Comment: yes I would like to see that too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [R.reject](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject) (or [R.filter](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter)) to remove properties from an object using a callback:

```js
const obj = {
  matrimonyUrl: 'christian-grooms',
  search_criteria:
    'a:2:{s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:9:"community";s:9:"Christian";}',
  mothertongue: null,
  religion: 'Christian',
  caste: '',
  country: null
};

const result = R.reject(R.equals(''))(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do I use `filter`?

Comment: With R.complement - `R.filter(R.complement(R.equals)(''))` Filter everything which is not equal to ''

Answer (score 6):

I did it like that,
but I was also needed to exclude the nullable values, not only the empty one.

```
const obj = { a: null, b: '',  c: 'hello world' };

const newObj = R.reject(R.anyPass([R.isEmpty, R.isNil]))(obj);
```

< --- only C going to display after

```
newObj = { c: 'hello world' }
```

Basically Reject is like filter but not include the results. doing filter(not(....), items)
If any of my conditions pass it will reject the specific key.

Hope It's helps!

Answer (score 2):

Are you ok to use pure javascript for this ? (no Ramda)

If you really need to remove a property from an object, you  can use [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```
for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] === "") {
        delete obj[key];
    }
}
```

If you prefer one-liner :

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(e => {if (e[1] === "") delete obj[e[0]]});
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove undefined values you can use `isNil`

```js
const obj = {
  matrimonyUrl: 'christian-grooms',
  search_criteria:
    'a:2:{s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:9:"community";s:9:"Christian";}',
  mothertongue: undefined,
  religion: 'Christian',
  caste: '',
  country: undefined
};

const result = R.reject(R.isNil)(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a pure javascript answer:

```js
const obj = {
  matrimonyUrl: 'christian-grooms',
  search_criteria:
    'a:2:{s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:9:"community";s:9:"Christian";}',
  mothertongue: null,
  religion: 'Christian',
  caste: '',
  country: null,
};

// Iterate over obj keys
const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => ({
  // Return the accumulator obj on every iteration
  ...acc,
  // Decide if we want to return the current {key:value} pair 
  ...(obj[key] !== '' ? { [key]: obj[key] } : {}),
// Initialize the accumulator obj
}), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
reject(complement(identity))
({
  matrimonyUrl: 'christian-grooms',
  search_criteria:
    'a:2:{s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:9:"community";s:9:"Christian";}',
  mothertongue: null,
  religion: 'Christian',
  caste: '',
  country: null
})


{"matrimonyUrl": "christian-grooms",
"religion": "Christian", 
"search_criteria": "a:2:{s:6:\"gender\";s:4:\"Male\";s:9:\"community\";s:9:\"Christian\";}"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const obj = {
  matrimonyUrl: 'christian-grooms',
  search_criteria:
    'a:2:{s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:9:"community";s:9:"Christian";}',
  mothertongue: null,
  religion: 'Christian',
  caste: '',
  country: null
};

const result = R.reject(R.equals(''))(obj);

console.log(result);
```