# Ramda: How to remove keys in objects with null values, empty arrays and empty lists recursively?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ramda.js

Similar to [Ramda: How to remove keys in objects with empty values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618149/ramda-how-to-remove-keys-in-objects-with-empty-values) but I am looking for something that works recursively.  This is so I can workaround a "feature" of AJV and JSON Schema where `null !== undefined`.

I started with this... which is to remove the nulls but does not work recursively

```
import R from 'ramda';
describe('filter null values', () => {
  it('should filter out null values', () => {
    const specimen = {
      tasks: [
        { id: 'foo', blank: '', zero: 0, nool: null },
        { nool: null },
        { id: '', blank: null, zero: 0, nool: null },
      ],
      useless: { nool: null },
      uselessArray: [{ nool: null }],
      nool: null,
    };
    const expectation = {
      tasks: [
        { id: 'foo', blank: '', zero: 0 },
        { id: '', zero: 0 },
      ],
    };
    const removeNulls = R.reject(R.equals(null));
    expect(removeNulls(specimen)).toEqual(expectation);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the passed item. If the value is an Object (or Array), recursively call `removeNulls` on the current value. After mapping the values, reject all `undefined`, `null`, or empty non string values (see `R.isEmpty`).

```js
const { pipe, map, when, is, reject, ifElse, F, either, isEmpty, isNil } = R;

const removeNulls = pipe(
  map(when(is(Object), v => removeNulls(v))),
  reject(ifElse(is(String), F, either(isEmpty, isNil))),
);

const specimen = {"tasks":[{"id":"foo","blank":"","zero":0,"nool":null},{"nool":null},{"id":"","blank":null,"zero":0,"nool":null}],"useless":{"nool":null},"uselessArray":[{"nool":null}],"nool":null};

const result = removeNulls(specimen);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```